# Tag cloud font size calculation logic

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

This is driving me insane. I am displaying a tag cloud based on the count of a tag in the database based on a % value. I noticed that when one tag was retrived, the associated font size was huge (because 100% was retrieved), so some suggested I do this:

```
var tagSummaryNegative = from af in db.AgileFactors
                     join psf in db.ProjectStoryFactors on af.AgileFactorID equals psf.AgileFactorID
                     join s in db.Stories on psf.StoryID equals s.StoryID
                     join pim in db.ProjectIterationMembers on s.ProjectIterationMemberID equals pim.ProjectIterationMemberID
                     join it in db.Iterations on pim.ProjectIterationID equals it.ProjectIterationID
                     join pro in db.Projects on it.ProjectID equals pro.ProjectID
                     where pro.ProjectID == pro_id &&
                           pro.ProjectID == it.ProjectID &&
                           it.ProjectIterationID == pim.ProjectIterationID &&
                           pim.ProjectIterationMemberID == s.ProjectIterationMemberID && s.StoryCategoryID == 1 &&
                           s.StoryID == psf.StoryID &&
                           psf.AgileFactorID == af.AgileFactorID
                     group af by af.Name into tagGroup

                     select new
                     {

                         Tag = tagGroup.Key,
                         tagCount = tagGroup.Count()

                     };

int maxTagFrequencyNegative = (from t in tagSummaryNegative select (int?)t.tagCount).Max() ?? 0;

var tagCloudNegative = from af in db.AgileFactors
                   join psf in db.ProjectStoryFactors on af.AgileFactorID equals psf.AgileFactorID
                   join s in db.Stories on psf.StoryID equals s.StoryID
                   join pim in db.ProjectIterationMembers on s.ProjectIterationMemberID equals pim.ProjectIterationMemberID
                   join it in db.Iterations on pim.ProjectIterationID equals it.ProjectIterationID
                   join pro in db.Projects on it.ProjectID equals pro.ProjectID
                   where pro.ProjectID == pro_id &&
                         pro.ProjectID == it.ProjectID &&
                         it.ProjectIterationID == pim.ProjectIterationID &&
                         pim.ProjectIterationMemberID == s.ProjectIterationMemberID && s.StoryCategoryID == 1 &&
                         s.StoryID == psf.StoryID &&
                         psf.AgileFactorID == af.AgileFactorID
                   group af by af.Name into tagGroup
                   select new
                   {

                       Tag = tagGroup.Key,
                       **weight = (tagGroup.Count() == 1) ? (double)1 : ((double)tagGroup.Count() / maxTagFrequencyNegative * 100)**
                   };
```

Now, when count is 1, font is small, but when 2, it's back to being huge again. The tags with the smaller count get smaller relative to the tag with the largest count - but I need it to start small and keep growing. Please help!

```
public string GetTagSize(double weight)
{

    if (weight >= 99)
        return "36pt";
    else if (weight >= 80)
        return "29pt";
    else if (weight >= 64)
        return "23pt";
    else if (weight >= 48)
        return "18pt";
    else if (weight >= 32)
        return "14pt";
    else if (weight >= 10)
        return "11pt";
    else
        return "8pt";
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `maxTagFrequencyNegative`?  Why would you use a negative value for dividing?

Comment: It's not a negative value - I'm using LINQ...maxTagFrequencyNegative is just an alias for the tags with associated negative stories...

Comment: +1 for recommending being nice to people, it only fosters a good community if you reward answers you liked/used

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rad Tag Cloud Control and you work will be easier. 
Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
int expectedSize = 36; //Or whatever the max size should be
double size = weight / tagGroup.count(); 
size = max(0, min(size, 1); //bounds size to between 1 and 0 just incase
//I'm assuming tagGroup.count() returns the number of tags. replace this as need

size = size * expectedSize;

return (int)size + "pt";
```

The idea being that you get the relative size of the tag between 1 and 0 then multiply this by the expected size.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be the value of `maxTagFrequencyNegative`.

Based on your code:
When weight > 98, font size should be at it's largest.
When weight < 10, font size is smallest.

Try the following:

```
weight = (tagGroup.Count() == 1) ? 
    (double)1 : ((double)tagGroup.Count() / maxTagCount * 100)
```

Where maxTagCount is the the largest number of tags, for any given tag.

To test this, try manually setting `maxTagCount` yourself to something close to the largest tag count, and see if your results are reasonable.